# Class 'DOMDocument' not found in Joomla

Tags: php, apache, joomla

My Joomla site got `Class 'DOMDocument' not found` error.

I tried installing dom by `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml` and restarted my apache.

Already add 'extension=dom.so' in my php.ini file and restarted apache.

Still, no DOM section appear in my info.php page.

I used 
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 
Apache/2.4.20 
PHP 7.0.8-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )

Now, I have no idea where to check anymore. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I updated my apache and machine by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and solved it in a different way.

Within **cPanel** I had an option to **change the PHP version** and set the options, from there I could choose a "dom" tickbox which solved my problem.

All cPanels can be slightly different so you may not have this option but hopefully it helps someone.